# Are there any secure methods to open other people's json text in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, security, fabricjs

When a user opens a json with fabric.js `StaticCanvas.loadFromJSON`, the function of `object.clipTo` or `pattern.source` is created by `new Function` and get executed.

Therefore, any function get executed when a user opens other people's json.
For example, a cracker can make any function in console as

```
fabric.Object.prototype.clipTo = function(){console.log('Hello World!');}
```

I made a example in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6jtvn03a/12/.

Are there any secure solutions to open other people's json?